# Windows 7 is making weird sounds while copying,deleting or doing anything to files on a pendrives

Tags: windows, usb, audio, usb-flash-drive

I have Windows 7 Ultimate, my computer is pretty old (somewhere around 8 years already?). And it makes really weird, beepy-like sounds while copying files to **any pendrive**(so it's a Windows issue, not unvalid pendrive). It's pretty creepy, but also funny and weird.

**About the sound:**

The sound goes in 1 pattern but sometimes it does some "extra" sounds, pretty hard to explain, but I feel like playing some old 8-bit RPG game. 
It's hearable in headphones, but also in speakers. The fun fact is, that even when I disable all of my sound and/or put all the volume levels to 0 - "the sound" is still here, haunting my ears. Also, when the copying is almost done - "the sound" sounds different, and it's more rapid.
A small sound can be heard when I **JUST CLICK ON**(select) any pendrive's file.

**I've tried**:

to change default format in Windows' settings, but nothing seems to fix it.
Changing the USB port doesn't work, also I'll mention again that this sound occurs with EVERY PENDRIVE

I'd like to know:
1. Why?! 
2. How to destroy that sound and live happily.

Comment: Classic symptom of interference between your PC and your audio output devices. It'll be quite hard to resolve as it could be your PSU, hard drive, old speakers, bad audio connectors etc.

Comment: Well, it's not about speakers, because on my headphones I can hear the same exact thing

Comment: You are hearing interference from the motherboard, this is usual with integrated sound adapters.  eg. My new motherboard has an optional power socket _just_ for the integrated audio, specifically to help avoid this type of thing...

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like interference.(Headphones which are speakers and speakers can fall victim to this type of interference). Also when you are copying files on anything it can cause electrical interference throughout the system causing the interference. My old speaker system is starting to fall victim to this as well. I can barely touch the base box and it will crackle. Sometimes I can hear truckers, Phone calls, and even odd radio stations in my speakers. The first time I thought I was going crazy, Especially when I could hear some people talk on a phone but I could only hear one side of the call. This interference will still happen if the speaker volume is set to 0. I am 100% sure it is interference from what you describe. My solution is to turn up the volume to wash out the quiet interference.

Think of it like this, Have you ever listened to an old box radio and when you get bad signal you go to adjust the antenna, and when you touch it, the sound comes in clear. But when you move away it gets static again. Several things cause interference with any type of speakers with so many signals polluting the air. I would try moving the speaker setup and see if that helps. Also try to go with a better quality speaker, headphone combo so that they will have better quality shielding to help block out interference. (I have noticed the cheap dollar store speakers and headphones have more interference than a better quality set. )

Comment: trenten - have you definitively ruled out that you were going crazy? :-)

Comment: Haha yes I have. It freaked me out the first time because I was laying down and hearing voices. Then I walked to the speakers and was hearing truck drivers talking, That was with the volume set to 0. So I just shut them off. It kinda depends on where you are and if the signal has to pass by your speakers. :)